# Why is chroot needed while installing GRUB?

Tags: grub2, chroot

I am trying to dual boot my laptop with linux alongside windows. Now one of the things I will probably need to do is that first install linux to my desired partition and then boot from a live cd and then select my boot partition and then install and configure grub on my boot partition.

Instructions are listed [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_ChRoot).

Now what I find redundant is that why do I need to `chroot` if the installation command is as follows -:

```
grub-install /dev/sd1
```

What was the use of chrooting or even mounting the linux partitions if grub can just simply install to a partition of my choice from the command line ?

Why would I even mount the virtual filesystems in the following manner -:

```
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
```

Is it because when I have booted into live mode from my installation disk the grub files are present in the installed Linux OS that I must access in order for the installation to proceed ? ie. to be able to run `grub-install` ?

If the grub files are there on the installation media then it seems pretty irrelevant to do the mounting and chrooting ?

Correct me if I am wrong but all that `chroot` does is change the root directory of the current and child process, right ?

Comment: @Fox Yes I want specific settings. The question was why was the chroot neded if grub-install has an option to install to a specific partition. I will not be installing GRUb during Linux installation, since I need to configure chainloading of Windows from Grub.

Comment: @Fox I have an UEFI system so the default installations won't work. Just tell me something, the /boot/grub directories are they present in the installed linux system or are they present on the installation media ? in other words do I chroot to just get access to /boot/grub directories ? I can just copy them into my EFI partition without a chroot

Comment: @Fox yeah so if the installation media has GRUB why `chroot` into it ? If I use an Ubuntu image to install to my system and use the same image to do a live boot to install GRUB why is chrooting required ?

Comment: @Fox Well there is a few things to do manually in my experience, since the chainloading for windows needs to configured, especially if you are using an EFI system

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58489/discussion-between-fox-and-ng-newbie).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At boot time, GRUB needs to be able to find and read files from `/boot/grub`.

Therefore, GRUB needs to know the disk and partition that contain `/boot/grub` **before** GRUB can read files from inside `/boot/grub`.

Therefore, `grub-install` needs to embed this disk and partition inside of GRUB itself.

Therefore, `grub-install` needs to know (or needs to be able to deduce) the disk and partition that contain `/boot/grub`.  (Or at least this is what I suspect is the case.)

`grub-install` is designed to deduce the disk and partition of `/boot/grub` by determining the disk and partition of `/boot/grub` **in the environment** that `grub-install` itself is running in.

In other words, `grub-install` is **designed** with the **assumption** that `grub-install` itself will be running **inside** the system that GRUB will boot.

Therefore, you need to `chroot` into the system you want to boot so that `/boot/grub` at the time you run `grub-install` is the same as `/boot/grub` in the system you want to boot.